# What is the expected accuracy of eddystone localisation accross devices?

Tags: android, eddystone, btle

We consider to use Google eddystone technology for indoor localisation. Due to our experiences with other beacon technologies we are concerned about the impact of different devices. The main reason for the differences might be the position of the bt chip (and its antenna) on the device, the bt chip itself and the drivers. Should we expect this differences also for eddystone? Or is google able to provide a more consistent accuracy? (Of course the Android people can not work around every limitation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that Eddystone leverages Bluetooth LE just like other beacon formats.  **The device-specific hardware variances you describe affect Bluetooth LE in general** and not any one beacon format.  Systems using Eddystone are subject to the same hardware limitations and performance variations, so **the same level of accuracy can be expected with Eddystobe as when working with other formats.**